# Find and show threads traces with selected package (by regex) in running Java application

Tags: java, debugging, remote-debugging

My problem comes from real practice: I have an application, that depends on external (network) services. If some service become inaccessible my application freeze and I don't understand where problems come from.

I don't write application myself and source code doesn't used logging if something go wrong.

I run **jconsole** and see all threads with traces (like do this with **procexp** in my previous job for Windows native application). But there are 120 threads!!

So I want to find threads there some classes (or regex pattern for package/class) in trace and print that traces. So I find place where network wait take place.

**jconsole** application shown that this theoretically possible to do (but I really don't want clicks to all of 120 threads in **jconsole** interface I search by eyes there my packages).

Do I need to run a full debugger **jdb**? Do I need to start my app (which actually Spring application in Jboss application server) with some option to allow retrieving such info?

I am old live Emacs user, so dumping all thread with traces of locally running application by command line utility also resolve my problem.

I prefer connection to normally (without any debug tuning) running application as this seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run **jvisualvm** visit *"Threads"* tab and press *"Thread dump"* button and get asked info!!

So I can save report to file and perform searching in *Emacs* with regex.

I just forget that **jconsole** *deprecated* as only recently back to Java world (from low level C world).

But fill free point me to non-interactive command line solution...

**UPDATE** `kill -QUIT $pid` make Java process to dump thread traces to stdout. `jps -l` help to find Java process. If stdin redefined (Tomcat AS, etc) - check out AS logs!

Comment: If you don't mind using emacs, take a look at https://github.com/nd/thread-dump.el - this is emacs thread-dump viewer.